# how to set SliverAppBar flexibleSpace height base on child content

Tags: flutter, dart

i have custom widget in flexibleSpace and i want to set expandedHeight base on flexibleSpace content but how

```
 SliverAppBar(
      pinned: true,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      // expandedHeight: 500,
      flexibleSpace: buildDetail(),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm trying to solve your Problem :**

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SliverExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<SliverExample> {
  double _flexibleSpaceHeight = 200.0;

  void _updateFlexibleSpaceHeight(double height) {
    setState(() {
      _flexibleSpaceHeight = height;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              expandedHeight: _flexibleSpaceHeight,
              flexibleSpace: MyFlexibleSpace(
                onUpdateHeight: _updateFlexibleSpaceHeight,
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('Item $index'),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyFlexibleSpace extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(double height) onUpdateHeight;

  const MyFlexibleSpace({Key? key, required this.onUpdateHeight})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyFlexibleSpaceState createState() => _MyFlexibleSpaceState();
}

class _MyFlexibleSpaceState extends State<MyFlexibleSpace> {
  double _height = 200.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
  }

  void _afterLayout(_) {
    widget.onUpdateHeight(_height);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        _height = constraints.maxHeight;
        return FlexibleSpaceBar(
          background: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://picsum.photos/500/200',
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'FlexibleSpaceBar Content',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but the height is defined in expandedHeight property in SliverAppBar not in flexibleSPace

Comment: check my answer i will update

Comment: it's glitchy and only work once

Comment: @CCP Check My Answer hope so it working fine for you